# Multiple value in textbox from same class

Tags: jquery

My HTML:

```
<div class="main"> <input type="text" id="calculation"> </div>
<hr>
<div class="main"> <input type="text" id="query"> </div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="class" value="1">1</button> <button class="class" value="2">2</button> <button value="3">3</button> <button value="4">4</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var inputs = $(".class");
$(inputs).click(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    $(inputs[i]).val();
    $('#query').val($(this).val());
  }
});
```

I Just want to get multiple value with same class but using for Loop also not Working.

Comment: Share your HTML also

Comment: Show us what is `#query` and `.1class` element actually is

Comment: <div class="main">
   <input type="text" id="calculation" >
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="main">
   <input type="text" id="query">
  </div>
  <div>
   <table>
    <tr>
     <td><button class="class" value="1">1</button>
      <button class="class" value="2">2</button>
      <button value="3">3</button>
      <button value="4">4</button>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </div>

Comment: First of, a class should not start with a number, second you say `multiple value with same id`, so if multiple elements have the same id, then you got a problem, because an ID should always be unique.

Comment: @QamberJamani Please add HTML code to your question and Please take some time to read the help page, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i am so confused and this is my first time in stackoverflow

Comment: @QamberJamani it is still unclear on what is your expected output

Answer (score 0):

Use `+=` to get multipal value of same class and show in your field.

```js
var inputs = $(".1class");
var value = '';
$(inputs).click(function() {
  $('#query').val('');
  //value = '' //uncomment this one to clear text box before append value otherwise it's append new value to previous one whenever you click. 
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    value += $(inputs[i]).val();
  }
  $('#query').val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main"> <input type="text" id="calculation"> </div>
<hr>
<div class="main"> <input type="text" id="query"> </div>
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="1class" value="1">1</button> <button class="1class" value="2">2</button> <button value="3">3</button> <button value="4">4</button> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet :

```
$arr = [];
$(".class").each(function(){
  var i = $(this).val();//get input value
  $arr.push(i);//array of all values
});
```